# How can I cancel Notification Center Visual Effect (iOS) for an specific view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, ios8-today-widget

I have applied my function `applyVibrancy` on the `viewDidLoad` method of my `mainViewController` for my Today Widget application.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   applyVibrancy()
} 

func applyVibrancy()
{
    let oldView = self.view
    var effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect.notificationCenterVibrancyEffect())

    effectView.frame = oldView.bounds
    effectView.autoresizingMask = oldView.autoresizingMask;

    effectView.userInteractionEnabled = true    
    effectView.contentView.addSubview(oldView)        
    self.view.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    self.view = effectView
 }
```

This successfully applies this visual effect into my entire widget. But I would like to have some of my nested views (Labels, Buttons, Images, etc) to **NOT** be affected by this effect.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the effect you desire, for the views that you want to has this effect, add them to the `contentView` of a `UIVisualEffectView`, which then is added as subview of `self.view`. For other views not to be affected, add them to `self.view` directly.

When I run your code, I get a black screen.

> UIVibrancyEffect amplifies and adjusts the color of content layered
>   behind the view, allowing content placed inside the contentView to
>   become more vivid. It is intended to be placed over, or as a subview
>   of, a UIVisualEffectView that has been configured with a UIBlurEffect.
>   This effect only affects content added to the contentView.

`notificationCenterVibrancyEffect` is a kind of UIVibrancyEffect, but in your code there is no UIVisualEffectView with a UIBlurEffect configured, you should create one, and place your `effectView` over that view or add your `effectView` as subview of that view's contentView. Otherwise you will not see any vibrancy.

Here is some test code.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 30)
label.text = "Has Vibracy!"

let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect.notificationCenterVibrancyEffect())

effectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 30)
effectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
effectView.userInteractionEnabled = true

effectView.contentView.addSubview(label)

let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark))
blurView.contentView.addSubview(effectView)
blurView.frame = CGRectMake(80, 20, 130, 30)

self.view.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

let label1 = UILabel()
label1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 60, 130, 30)
label1.text = "No Vibracy!"

self.view.addSubview(blurView)
self.view.addSubview(label1)
```

Comment: Hi gabbler, I'm trying just to cancel the effect for some views inside a view container that has this effect already applied.

Comment: Once applied, I find no api to cancel it, but you can change view structures, let self.view has two view containers, both frame are self.view.bounds, move all subviews you want to cancel the effect to container A, other subviews to container B, apply the effect to container B.